# How do I turn a number of pins to high and then off after 5 seconds based on a serial command

Tags: serial, led, timers

I have an Arduino sketch where I'm sending commands over serial, and as a result turning pins from low to high. What I'm looking to do is have those pins turn high for 5 seconds and then turn back to low. I was looking for a time or scheduling library for Arduino that allows multiple timers at once and lets you pass a parameter (at least I think that's what I need).

In other words, I would like to implement a "doAfter" method and pass the function it is calling a pin number.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `delay()` function? Try putting this in the `loop()` function for pin 3.

```
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
delay(1000); // time in milliseconds as parameter
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Timer library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer) to achieve this:

```
#include "Timer.h"
[...]
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
int afterEvent = t.after(5000, doAfter);
[...]
void doAfter() {
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
}
```

As you can see, you cannot pass a parameter to the timer, just a callback. I suggest that you implement either a bunch of `doAfter` functions, from `doAfter3` to doAfter9` for instance, and call the right one in the callback.

There are probably other timer libraries, but this one is simple and complete enough for your needs.